# Apache solr does not respond only from a specific IP in Digital Ocean

Tags: solr, digital-ocean

I can not make the Apache Solr installation respond successfully.

I comment quickly, I have a Wordpress droplet in digital ocean, I installed Apache sorl and apparently it is running correctly.

```
$ service solr status
● solr.service - LSB: Controls Apache Solr as a Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/solr; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2019-06-18 20:20:55 UTC; 1 day 9h ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4342 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/solr stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 4458 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/solr start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0
```

The ip xxx.xx.xxx.xxx is my droplet IP, and I only want from this IP queries can be made to apache sorl.

```
$ ufw status
WARN: / is group writable!
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                              
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8983                       ALLOW       xxx.xx.xxx.xxx            
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

If I filter the ips to see if as is configured

```
$ sudo netstat -lntp | grep 8983
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8983          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4507/java
```

Ping from inside of my droplet server (ssh).

```
$ ping http://localhost:8983/solr
ping: unknown host http://localhost:8983/solr
```

How to get an answer from apache solr, what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

First, what you're seeing is caused by Solr only listening to the loopback interface by default. This is to avoid people inadvertently exposing Solr directly to the internet (which it is not meant for). The netstat command shows this:

```
tcp        0      0 --> 127.0.0.1:8983 <--
```

To change what interface Solr listens to, you can add `-Djetty.host=<ip>` to the SOLR_OPTS used when starting Solr. How this is done depends on how you've installed Solr, but usually through `solr.in.sh` or something similar.

Second: Make sure your firewall is set to disallow connections by default, otherwise the single Allow for the port won't change anything. Test this from outside your host to make sure you're not exposing Solr to the whole internet.

Third: `ping` does not work like that. `ping <ip>` is how you'd use the `ping` utility, and this sends an ICMP packet to the ip (or host which is resolved to an ip) and waits for a response. It'll not work against a `http` URL, a given port or an endpoint path.

Comment: @MatsLindth i have the same problem here. I have set the the SOLR_JETTY_HOST to 0.0.0.0. But after restart it's already listening to 127.0.0.1. Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This has come up for us with an upgrade from Solr v7 to v9 and as the syntax appears to have changed a little since MatsLindh's useful reply I thought I would document it here.

For Windows installations, you should update the file `Solr.in.cmd`, which is located in `c:\solr-9.0.0\bin` as standard.

At the bottom add in the two lines:

```
set SOLR_JETTY_HOST=0.0.0.0

set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dsolr.jetty.host=0.0.0.0
```

If you use `0.0.0.0` as shown here you'll open up Solr to any call. You can replace `0.0.0.0` with a hostname or a specific IP address if you wish.

Final point: I found it necessary to reboot the server for this to take effect, despite what I saw on the Solr admin page after restarting the Windows service using the Solr